# Google console block URLs robots.txt redirection 301

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my website, I have some urls with the following shape :
https://www.MyShop.com/648-category-name?n=50&amp%253Bn=10&id_category=81

Such urls are created when a visitor changes the default quantity products per page from 20 (default value) to 50.

There is no need to index such urls. In addition such urls could be regarded as duplicate content.

1- In robots.txt, I put the following directive  :

- Disallow: /*n=

2- In Google console Urls setting, I added the following parameter :

- n=
- *Does this parameter change page content seen by the user ?*
- I set : Yes: Changes, reorders, or narrows page content
- *How does this parameter affect page content :*
- I set : Other

  *Which URLs with this parameter should Googlebot crawl :
- I set : No URLs

3- However having done this, in Google console, I am getting a message saying that the url is blocked (on Smartphone, not on computer).
It seems that the Googlebot-mobile crawler :

- indexes Urls that are supposed to be ignored by the robots.txt
  directive (from what I found on the internet, it seems no unsual)
- ignores the Google console Urls settings

4- To solve the matter, I wonder whether it is possible **to make a 301 redirection

- from any urls with n=
- to the url content located before the question mark**

Would anyone know what line should be added in the htaccess file to make such a redirection ?

I thank anyone in advance for any help in this matter.

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want this to target the bots only, probably by matching the user agent:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|google-mobile) [NC]
```

If you want to strip all URLs containing a query string to the bare URL, you can use the below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

If you only wanted to redirect for a *specific* query string component, such as `n=foo`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

If you're using an apache version older than 2.4 that doesn't support the [`QSD`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag, simply append a `?` to `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead.

---

**Edit 1:**

That's very odd. The query string in this URI:

```
https://www.MyShop.com/648-category-name?%252525252525253Bn=10
```

Contains a semicolon `;` which was [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) into `%3B` but then the percent sign `%` was encoded again into `%25` over and over.

Without addressing how to fix that particular issue, you could modify the regex I stated above to match the percent-encoding as well with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)([%A-Za-z0-9]+)n=(.+)(&|$)
```

Or a simpler, if somewhat less targeted:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(.+)n=(.+)(&|$)
```

But that would also match any query string component that happened to end with `n=`, so this URI:

```
https://www.MyShop.com/648-category-name?somethingn=foo&id_category=42
```

Would be captured as well.

Since you're only targeting bots, it might be best to just strip the query strings completely. If this is only an issue on specific parts of the site, you can also narrow down the locations on the site it would apply to by putting those rewrite rules in a `location` block:

```
<location /648-category-name>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|google-mobile) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . # Or any of the other regexes
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
</location>
```

Alternatives to this, which may or may not be feasible for you, would be adding a [`rel="canonical"` meta tag](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114814), or adding `Disallow: /*?*` in your robots.txt to stop all crawling of pages with query strings, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149936).

---

**Edit 2:**

There are more efficient ways to write those rules.

Multiple conditions, separated by the apache [`[OR]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=10(.+)(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=20(.+)(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=50(.+)(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)amp%(.+)(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)%25252525(.+)(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

As a single condition, with the regex [`|` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=(10|20|50|amp%|%25)(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

This might matter for performance reasons on high traffic sites.

Comment: Thank you very much Eddie for your reply.

Comment: Thank you very much Eddie for your reply. I added the following in the htaccess file, and it worked : RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]. But I have also got some urls, for which I did not manage to find the right 301 redirection. Suchs urls have the following structure :  https://www.MyShop.com/648-category-name?%252525252525253Bn=10. Would you know how to redirect those urls to  https://www.MyShop.com/648-category-name. Thank you very much again in advance for any help. Patrick

Comment: Thank you again Eddie. I finally added 5 redirection to the htaccess file. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=10(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=20(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=50(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)amp%(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)%25252525(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I finally added 5 redirections to htaccess file : RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=10(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=20(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)n=50(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)amp%(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)%25252525(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]. I did not matched specifically a user agent.

Comment: There might be an easier way to write that, see my edit.